# Syntax error near unexpected token `elif'

Tags: bash, shell

```
./chkf: line 30: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
'/chkf: line 30: `elif [ -f "$object" ] ; then


if [ -d "$object" ] ; then
    message="$message a directory"
elif [ -f "$object" ] ; then
    message="$message a regular file."
else
    message="$message not a known file type"
fi
```

Also this,

```
./chkf: line 38: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
'/chkf: line 38: `else 

if [ -w "$object" ] ; then
    write="writeable"
else 
    write="not writeable"
fi
```

What is wrong with this? It seems to be correct. I tried so many variations and cannot figure out what is wrong. Is there some kind of invisible character? If so, is there a command to strip it?

**Edit:** When I add `#!/bin/bash` at the top, I get the following error:

```
interpreter "/bin/bash" not found
file link resolves to "/usr/bin/bash"
-bash: ./chkf: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What shell are you using? Rather than fragments, please post a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What version? `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: Works fine for me with 4.1.5(1)-release, might be something in your old version or perhaps some other if block open?

Comment: I just tested it on another server, and it didn't get those errors. Perhaps it has something to do with me editing using Secure File Transfer Client and using Notepad++?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's your line endings. Transferring it from Windows has left the `CR/LF` line endings on.

When I create a script then manually add the `CR` characters, I get exactly the same error:

```
qq.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
'q.sh: line 3: `elif [ 1 == 1 ] ; then
```

You can fix it by removing the CR character from CR/LF line endings.

```
cat script.sh | sed 's/\r$//' >newscript.sh
```

Comment: Nice catch.  `dos2unix` is a handy utility installed on many systems, removes the CRs inplace.

Comment: If you are using vim as editor, you can set ":set ff=unix" and write to file again.

Comment: Another hint to the sed solution: `sed '/\015/d' < script.sh > newscript.sh` will do it without cat.

Answer (score 5):

Two ways to resolve this

1) Using **Sed**:-

Syntax

```
sed -i 's/\r//' filename.txt
```

2) Using **dos2unix** command

Syntax

```
dos2unix fileName.txt fileName.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

it looks like you've got the "dos problem", embedded control-M's in your file. fix it with sed:

```
sed -i 's/\r//' chkf
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've added the additional error message, I have a thought: the `^M` is \r, which is the Mac OS X line ending or part of the Windows line ending - Linux uses \n only as EOL. If you edit in `vim`, you should be able to see the `^M` if it's not right through the file.

Comment: OS X uses `\n` just like Linux and Unix (since it is a member of the family). Old Mac OS versions once used `\r`.

Comment: @Dennis: I see; didn't realise it had changed between OS and OS X.