# Basic bash script issue

Tags: bash

Here is my first post on the forum, let me know if I may be more descriptif.
Yesterday, I script a lil' script to start, restart and stop my server in one, so I test 3 times the $1 argument to know if it's start, restart, stop string.

I take all the improvments if I can do it in another way :)

Here is my code :

```
#!/bin/bash
STA="start"
RES="restart"
STO="stop"
SERVERNAME="server_live"
if [ $1 -ge 1 ]
then
    echo "Entre un argument : start, stop, restart"
elif [ $1 = $STA ]
then
    screen -mdS $SERVERNAME
    screen -S $SERVERNAME -dm bash -c 'sleep 1;cd /home/cfx-server; bash run.sh;exec sh'
    echo "Serveur redémarré"
elif [ $1 = $RES ]
then
    screen -ls | grep $SERVERNAME | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
    screen -mdS $SERVERNAME
    screen -S $SERVERNAME -dm bash -c 'sleep 1;cd /home/cfx-server; bash run.sh;exec sh'
    echo "Serveur Restart"
elif [ $1 = $STO ]
then
    screen -ls | grep $SERVERNAME | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
    echo "Serveur Stoppé"
fi
```

I got the following error : 
[My code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhQRj.png)

It means : syntaxe error near inexpected symbol elif line 10

Thanks in advance.. I wanna add that

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "read smthg"
read name
```

put an error too (on read) , how might I know if I got a version issue or something like that ?

Comment: have you tried using double square brackets, e.g. elif [[ $1 = $STA ]] ?

Comment: the first if statement should use double brackets too, as it is expected that $1 will be a string and not a number (unless an incorrect entry is made)

Comment: Obviously, `$1` is not a number.  That should be `if [ $# -ne 1 ]`.

Comment: Looks like a line ending issue to me, e.g. writing the script on Windows and then running it on Linux. @LJH where did you get the idea that you have to `declare` the variable?

Comment: @TomFenech apparently in a wild dream. No idea why I have done so all this time; thanks anyway!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4182122/2088135

Comment: Consider using http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here -- and be sure to reduce the code in your question to a [mcve] with the simplest possible thing that creates the same error *before* asking! (Can you replace all the `screen` commands with `echo`s? Then you should be doing that. Can you remove some of the conditions? Then you should be doing that too).

Comment: Thanks you for your answers, thanks for sharing the shellcheck site :)
But apparently even with a double brackets I got an error

Comment: I believe that you have `^M` characters inside each lines (probably because you edit the file on windows and then transport it in unix?). use: `tr -d '\015' <script.bash >script-new.bash ; chmod +x script-new.bash` and try to launch `script-new.bash` instead . `^M` (octal : `015`, also known as "CR") is part of the "CR LF" windows "end of line" termination, where unix expect just an "LF".

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/1f88567de163e85bc591ef360f5e8820.png

@Olivier Dulac Thanks for answered, I try your command (I dunno what it is but nvm ^^) 
And you right I'm doing that, What should I do to avoid that ?

Answer (score 0):

you should use case instead of if ... elif, and (almost) always quote your variables between " " :

Please try this version (close to yours, but using case...esac and with some quotes added):

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVERNAME="server_live"

case "$1" in
  start)
    screen -mdS "$SERVERNAME"
    screen -S "$SERVERNAME" -dm bash -c 'sleep 1;cd /home/cfx-server; bash run.sh;exec sh'
    echo "Serveur redémarré"
    ;;
  restart)
    screen -ls | grep $SERVERNAME | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
    screen -mdS "$SERVERNAME"
    screen -S "$SERVERNAME" -dm bash -c 'sleep 1;cd /home/cfx-server; bash run.sh;exec sh'
    echo "Serveur Restart"
    ;;
  stop)
    screen -ls | grep $SERVERNAME | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
    echo "Serveur Stoppé"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "argument: '$1' non reconnu..."
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

If you encounter an error, your script may contain things before that part that interfere? Please first paste your script in : www.shellcheck.net  and see what it tells you (it will parse it and show a lot of common error, such as unclosed quotes, etc).

**EDIT**

The problem came from the fact that person was editing under windows (which uses 'CR-LF' line endings) and using it in linux/unix (which expected just LF, and thus took the CR as an additionnal character in the lines containing them).

To get rid of "everything non-printable" that isn't used for scripting in your script:

```
LC_ALL="C" tr -cd "[$(printf '\t')\$(printf '\n') -~]" <script.bash >script_without_nonprintables.bash
  # LC_ALL="C" just before tr makes tr use that environment, which gives "ascii" instead of whatever locale you use. This helps ensure the ranges given are the ascii ones, and not something else.
  # -c = complement, ie "whatever is not..."   -d="delete", so -cd= "delete whatever is not specified"
  #  [a-d] = from a to d in the current locale (ascii, here, thanks to LC_ALL="C", so it will be : a, b, c or d
  #   in ascii,  SPACE to ~  covers all the character you need to write scripts, except for TAB (\t) and Newline (\n), so I added those as well.
  #   for newline, I preceded it with an "\" to have it taken literally
chmod +x script_without_nonprintables.bash
```

Comment: Using `case` is a valid alternative but I don't think it directly solves the user's problem, which appears to be related to line endings in my opinion.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/fbc9b1b52b543260c040520e63d9afe5.png
Thanks for your message, I tried your script, it seems to retur error after in case $1.. It's weird

Comment: @Izio: you have "^M" characters inside each lines (probably because you edit the file on windows and then transport it in unix?). use:  tr -d '\015' < script.bash > script-new.bash  and try to launch script-new.bash .  ^M (octal : 015,  known as "CR") is part of the CR-LF windows "end of line" termination, where unix expect just an "LF".

Comment: @OlivierDulac You right, I'm doing that actually, I'm on sublime text, How should I transfer the code without errors ?

Comment: @Izio: it it working now that you get rid of the '\r' (^M, aka CR) characters? And to help, you can probably ask "subime" to use unix end-of-lines, or once transfered, just use the trick I gave you :  `tr -d '\015' <./script.bash >./script-new.bash && chmod +x ./script-new.bash && mv ./script-new.bash ./script.bash` (you can actually create a script file with this one-liner, and source it when needed)

Comment: Thanks you very very much :)

Comment: @Izio: you may also want to ensure you don't import "weird" (unicode?) characters into your scripts as well... you may extend my command to get rid of most of those:    `LC_ALL="C" tr -cd "[$(printf '\t\n') -~]" <script.bash >script_without_nonprintables.bash ; chmod +x script_withou*`  ( tr -cd 'something' will (c)omplement what is listed, and (d)elete those.  in ascii (forced thanks to the LC_ALL=C), space to ~ covers all you need to do scripting, except for return and tab, which i also added using printf (that way you can easily copy-paste)

Comment: @Izio: I corrected the one-liner, and included it in my answer.  the new one: `LC_ALL="C" tr -cd "[$(printf '\t')\$(printf '\n') -~]" <script.bash >script-sanitized.bash`

Comment: @OlivierDulac Excuse me but I'm not assuming what you are explaining, shall I run both commands or just the last ? just the first ?

Comment: @Izio the one included in my anwer. it gets rid of the unwanted weird characters (such as CR, ^M) but keeps the ones usefull for the script